# Clojure global variable behavior in a threaded environment

Tags: clojure, global-variables

Given that this works as I'd expect:

```
(do
  (println (resolve 'a)) ; nil 
  (def a "a")
  (println (resolve 'a))) ; #'user/a
```

I'd like to understand why this doesn't:

```
(future
  (println (resolve 'b)) ; #'user/b (shouldn't it be still undefined at this point?)
  (def b "b")
  (println (resolve 'b))) ; #'user/b
```

I'd also like to know if this is a proper solution (not exactly solving the same problem, but doing an equivalent job in my context):

```
(def c (atom nil))
(future
  (println @c) ; nil
  (reset! c "c")
  (println @c)) ; c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaviour comes about as a result of the way in which `def` forms are compiled.

Note that using `def` forms not at top-level (or perhaps inside a top-level `let` -- see below for more comments on this case) is frowned upon as a matter of style in any case. The snippet using an Atom, on the other hand, is fine -- no reason not to use it if it does what you want.

On to the `def` story:

1. Compilation of `def` forms:

   When a `def` form is encountered, a Var of the appropriate name is created *at that moment* by the compiler in the current namespace. (Attempting to `def` a Var outside the current namespace by using a namespace-qualified symbol as the name argument to `def` results in an exception). That Var is at first unbound and stays unbound until the `def` is actually executed; for a top-level `def`, that'll be right away, but for a `def` hidden inside a function's body (or inside a `let` form -- see below), that'll be when the function is called:

   ```
   ;;; in the user namespace:

   (defn foo []
     (def bar "asdf")
    :done)
   ; => #'user/foo

   bar
   ; => #<Unbound Unbound: #'user/bar>

   ;;; let's change the namespace and call foo:

   (ns some.ns)
   (user/foo)
   ; => :done

   bar
   ; exception, the bar Var was created in the user namespace!

   user/bar
   ; => "asdf"
   ; the Var's namespace is fixed at compile time
   ```
2. The first example -- with the `do` form:

   Top level `do`s are treated as if their contents were spliced into the flow of code at the place where the `do` occurs. So if you type `(do (println ...) (def ...) (println ...))` at the REPL, that's equivalent to typing in the first `println` expression, then the `def`, then the second `println` expression (except the REPL only produces one new prompt).
3. The second example -- with `future`:

   `(future ...)` expands to something close to `(future-call (fn [] ...))`. If `...` includes a `def` form, it'll be compiled in the manner we have seen above. By the time the anonymous function executes on its own thread the Var will have been created, thus `resolve` will be able to find it.
4. As a side note, let's have a look at a similar snippet and its output:

   ```
   (let []
     (println (resolve 'c)) 
     (def c "c") 
     (println (resolve 'c)))
   ; #'user/c
   ; #'user/c
   ; => nil
   ```

   The reason is as before with the extra point that `let` is first compiled, then executed as a whole. This is something one should keep in mind when using top-level `let` forms with definitions inside -- it's generally ok as long as no side-effecty code is intermingled with the definitions; otherwise one has to be extra careful.

Comment: As a curiosity it appears the behavior of `def` in a future call changed between clojure 1.2 and 1.3. I initially couldn't reproduce the results seen in the question but my "stand alone" repl was set to run the old version 1.2.

Comment: @Michal Many thanks for this clear explanation (that I would have had a really hard time figuring out by myself..)