# Clojure: Rebind a Symbol to a New Data Structure

Tags: binding, clojure, symbols

How do I rebind a symbol to a new data structure in Clojure.  For example:

```
 (def hash-map-one {:a "foo" :b "bar"})
 (def hash-map-two {:c "gaz" :d "waka"})

 ;; right here make hash-map-one equal to hash-map-two very quickly
 ;; if this were python I would say hash-map-one = hash-map-two
```

A little motivation, I'm doing this because I have a web service that depends on a data file, and that data file will be updated, at which point I need to, without downtime, "switch over" to the new data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, symbols are not storage locations in Clojure. The hash maps here are stored in Vars. These have symbolic names, which can, however, resolve to different Vars in different namespaces. (This applies even to namespace-qualified symbols because of aliases.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your use case, using an atom may make the most sense:

```
(def data (atom {:map 'of :initial "data"}))

(reset! data {:map 'of :new "data"})
```

If for some reason you prefer to use a Var, you can use `alter-var-root` to switch over to a new value. You could also use `intern`, although then you'd lose `alter-var-root`'s atomicity guarantee (see the docstring and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16457466/232707); the comment re: `def` is equally applicable to `intern`).

At the REPL, using `def` to rebind existing Vars is perfectly fine, however it's not usually a great idea in production code (some notable exceptions are found in the Clojure implementation -- a very special case). Above all, `def` should only ever be used in top-level forms which will immediately execute it; that is, it should be a top-level form itself, or part of the body of a top-level form like `let`. Otherwise [weirdness ensues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059936/clojure-global-variable-behavior-in-a-threaded-environment).

Comment: Awesome, thank you, great answer, Ill explore that now.  Hey I was just playing around in the repl and did a forehead smack when I did this:  `user=> (def x {:a 1 :b 2})
#'user/x
user=> (let [y {:c 3 :d 4}] (dosync (def x y)))`  If this is going to be a global variable (created at server startup in jetty), is this ok, or does it have some pitfalls?

Comment: Also if this is in a threaded websever like Jetty, I see yours will work, will a simple def statement?

Comment: I've edited the answer just now to add some extra details. `def` is not suitable for use inside a function (see the link at the end of the answer for a discussion of the reasons for that); use `intern` instead. Incidentally, the `dosync` in your first comment does nothing, as there are no Refs involved.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Michal.  I implemented the atom approach you laid out and I'm going to take it for a test drive this morning.  The data structure in question is actually a large prefix tree.  The tree is made at startup globally, and then swapped when a new one is available:  `(def prefix-tree-one (atom (make-prefix-tree)))`  then in defroutes `(compojure.core/GET "/internal/rebuild"
        (let [prefix-tree-two (make-prefix-tree)]
            (dosync
                (reset! prefix-tree-one prefix-tree-two)))
        "Rebuild Successful")`  I'm reading up on intern now.  Cheers.

Comment: Sounds good. NB. `dosync` does nothing for Atoms. It's only useful with Refs (and `alter` / `commute` / `ensure` / `ref-set`).

Comment: Ya I was just about to say, removed redundant dosync :)